# I am trying to print or write protected file /data/data/com.package/file in android logs

Tags: java, python, android, node.js, npm

I tried

```
File f = new File("/data/data/mypackge/test");
            f.setReadable(true);

Log.d("TEST", MainActivity.getFileContents(f));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
```

but its gives error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/mypackage/test: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at com.mypackage.MainActivity.getFileContents(MainActivity.java:58)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at com.mypackage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    ... 15 more
```

I tried most of changes in my code but can't get that please any one have solution answer to this thread any android version answer are welcome from android 5.1 to 9 my app has to write a file inside my app directory /data/data/myapp/file in central logs please help any one know this.

Comment: Before you try to get the content add `if(!f.exists()) return.`.

Comment: `/data/data/com.package` and `/data/data/package` and `/data/data/myapp`. Any more?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you need to do, first, check for f.exists()
`if(!f.exists()) return;`

Then, you need to make use of the `new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "path-to-your-file");`

This should safely create the link to the file.

**Edit**

If you want the data directory, use `getInternalFilesDir()`

Comment: is this will work on internal files because my app stored in internal memory in /data/data/ directory.?

Comment: I would appreciate if you select this answer as best answer.