# I am trying to create a android app which copy a file in another app using symlink and print in central Android logs

Tags: java, android, debugging, kotlin, adb

I created a app as my title mention I was able to successfully create a link of another app internal file to my app /data/data/myapp/file using symlink but when I am trying to print in logs it gives premission denied.eacess

Mycode:

```
package myapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    [@Override](/override)
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String deepPath = ("/data/data/" + getPackageName()) + "/x/x/x/x/";
        new File(deepPath).mkdirs();
        try {
            new File(Uri.decode(deepPath + "..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2Fsdcard%2Ftest.xml")).getCanonicalFile().getParentFile().mkdirs();
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ln -s /data/data/anotherapp/file /data/data/myapp/test").waitFor();
            File f = new File("/data/data/myapp/test");
            f.setReadable(true);
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
            intent.setClassName("com.truecaller", "com.truecaller.messaging.sharing.SharingActivity");
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", Uri.parse("file:///data/data/myapp/test"));
            startActivity(intent);

            Log.d("MYAPP", MainActivity.getFileContents(f));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
    }

    public static String getFileContents(final File file) throws IOException {
        final InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        boolean done = false;

        while (!done) {
            final String line = reader.readLine();
            done = (line == null);

            if (line != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
        }

        reader.close();
        inputStream.close();

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

the above code create a file which is already in another and create a symlink to my internal folder /data/data/myapp/file. but while I am trying to print that file in log an permission denied is occur

error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/myapp/test: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at com.mypackage.MainActivity.getFileContents(MainActivity.java:58)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at com.mypackage.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
03-16 00:53:19.897  4231  4231 W System.err:    ... 15 more
```

please correct my code and I has to print that file in log.
correct my code and paste in answer its really appreciated.
thank you

Comment: if any alternate solution is there that to read that file inside my app that /data/data/myapp/file please paste code in java

Answer (score 0):

Please, I gave you the correct answer 1 day ago at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60702957/13065380:

There are 2 things you need to do, first, check for f.exists()
`if(!f.exists()) return;`

Then, you need to make use of the `new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "path-to-your-file");`

This should safely create the link to the file, without permission denial.

**Edit**

If you want the data directory, use `getInternalFilesDir()`